# IEWebdriver: Cannot click on option element. Executing JavaScript click function returned an unexpected error

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing web page with large number of forms. 
The page has main form and couple of sub-forms. 
Specific sub-forms are rendered only when specific values are selected in main form.
Lately, the page was rebuilt, in a way that sub-forms are not visible in static page source. They are injected and rendered dynamically (most likely by java script, not sure though).

Below is a code sample from my tests. The tests work on Firefox and Chrome but fail on IE

```
if (!keyType.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println(keyTypeInput.isDisplayed());
            Select keyTypeSelector = new Select(keyTypeInput);          
            keyTypeSelector.selectByVisibleText(keyType);
        }
```

Note: keyTypeInput is WebElement. keyTypeInput.isDisplayed() returns true, but any call on keyTypeSelector of selectByIndex, selectByVisibleText etc. throws the following error:

> 2014-07-31 21:23:34,119 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO 
>   c.a.q.c.t.CustomTestListener log - LOG LISTENER:
>   folder=com.qa.devportal.tests.regression.RunAQuery;browser=INTERNET_EXPLORER10;test=verifyResponse;result=Failure;TESTHOST=local;SESSIONID=4a6cb35b-b0ef-4681-a6ea-64eaac64520c;SCREENSHOT=Can't
>   save screenshot.;ERROR=org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot
>   click on option element. Executing JavaScript click function returned
>   an unexpected error, but no error could be returned from Internet
>   Explorer's JavaScript engine. (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 110 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision:
>   '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27
>   11:29:39' System info: host: 'war-lpt-pstepn', ip: '10.138.1.72',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_45' Session ID:
>   4a6cb35b-b0ef-4681-a6ea-64eaac64520c Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0,
>   ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true,
>   ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer,
>   enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss,
>   version=10, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false,
>   handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http,
>   ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=,
>   takesScreenshot=true}]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.setSelected(Select.java:318)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.selectByIndex(Select.java:175)
>     at
>   com.qa.devportal.pages.ApiExplorerPage.apiRequestParamsFill(ApiExplorerPage.java:290)
>     at
>   com.qa.devportal.tests.regression.RunAQuery.verifyResponse(RunAQuery.java:95)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Did you have similar issues?

Comment: Could you provide some source code for the actual section of the page you are talking about?

Comment: I edited my main post by adding some source code.

Comment: @mutt: I have made a workaround. As Select object did not see any of actual dropdownlist values, but WebElement itself is visible, so in that one place I did: <br/> 

    *if (webDriver instanceof InternetExplorerDriver)*   {keyTypeInput.click();keyTypeInput.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);}

Comment: It sounds like the select element is not actually a select element, but something else that visually appears like a select element, but in the DOM is not.  could you provide the specific rendered html of the element on the page?

Comment: It is copied from Chromes 'examine element'. 
<select style="margin: 0" name="lookup_type" paramtype="template" title="name: lookup_type
style: template
required: true
"><option value="er">er</option><option value="abilitec">abilitec</option><option value="md5">md5</option></select>

Comment: could you provide the IE specific rendered code?  The chrome code looks consistent, but it is working in Chrome.  If it's dynamically generated then it might not be rendered the same way.  f12 should provide dev tools on IE.